# Adding ImageViews to RecyclerView Item Layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a `RecyclerView` with items, which sometimes should show sometimes up to three icons.
At the moment I am just adding `ImageViews` to the layout in the `onBind` metod dynamically, but sometimes the `ImageViews` are added to the wrong item.
I have read some other questions with Problems on loading images too, what's the best approach to do this?

Comment: In what situation does the error occurs

Comment: Can you post your adapter code

Comment: @Sam when I add a new item

Comment: Thats because of the viewholder. I had the same problems ones but I solved it. Ill post my code in a min.

Comment: can you show your RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: do you load images from local resources or the network?

Comment: Two things come to mind. (1) One row layout with three `ImageView`s, with `visibility` set to `gone` or `visible` depending on requirements, or (2) different view types for each row, by overriding [`getItemViewType()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/1219389)

Answer (score 0):

Define three ImageVies in your custom_row.xml or whatever you named it. Set the width on wrap content and the gravitiy on center_horizontal so it will shown nicely.
In your `onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder ivHolder, int position)` you have to do the following:
Dependent on the current position you set 1,2 or 3 of the imageview-visibilities on `GONE` OR `VISIBLE`. So the Images will always be centered in the horizontal.
Then you fill the imageviews with images. I think thats it. It worked for me.

Dont forget to define the 3 Imageviews in your `ItemViewHolder` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want/need any layout advise. The icons are not the only thing I have in my item layout. I know I can have three `ImageViews` in the layout from the beginning, but I thought there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

ViewHolder can be recycled from an another position, thus if you add views in the onBindViewHolder it needs **adding or removing (if exist)** them on position's dependency.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issues as you need to sync access to the holder. 
There are a few quite good libraries to handle this and other cases of bitmap caching, reusing, pooling.

you can use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for local and network images:

```
   Glide.with(context).load(items.get(i).getImage()).into(viewHolder.image);
```

or for only network images Volley or [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus) swithing to their NetworkImageView widget and then in the adapter:

```
image.setImageUrl(items.get(i).getImage(), imageLoader);
```

These may use different approaches but they all know what to do.

Comment: Does this work with adding ImageViews or should I have three ImageViews in every item, even if they shouldn't show an image?

Comment: u have to have the image views already in the holder. you create those in oncreate viewholder